# How to jQuery.post() an array to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

After searching through so many SO questions, I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I'm have no end of trouble trying to figure it out.

Here is where it is sent:

```
var $arr = [];

$.each(obj.list, function(key, i)
{
    $arr.push(i.name);
}); 

/* A quick console.log($arr) confirms it is getting the values and pushing them on the array fine, displaying "Array [ "foo", "bar", "baz" ] */

/* EDIT */ $.post("url.php", {arr: JSON.stringify($arr)});
```

The issue is in url.php. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    /* EDIT */ $arr = json_decode($_POST['arr']);
?>

<p></p>
List: <?
        foreach ($arr as $i) 
        {
            /* EDIT */ echo var_dump($i) . "<br>";
        }
        ?>
<p></p>
```

On the page, it displays:

```
/* EDIT */ List: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

How do I make it display the items as requested?

Comment: In your loop, let's `var_dump($i)` What is it says? Your `i` is an array for some reason. It seems to me, it shouldn't be that. Note: Do not use shorttags.

Comment: `var_dump` the $arr variable first and see if it's actually an array recognized by PHP. The syntax might be different.

Comment: `$i + "<br>";` use `.` to concat strings in php, not `+`

Comment: Like already said: var_dump first. But also: the plus sign is not a concatenator in PHP. The dot is.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I use that code (after hard coding the array you describe) the response is: List: 000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an object, containing the Array: `{arr: $arr}`.
However, JQuery/JS internally calls "$arr.toString()" to serialise the Array, which just results in the outputed string "Array".

In order to actually send the array, you need to JSON-encode it:

```
 $.post("url.php", {arr: JSON.stringify($arr)});
```

In your php, you then have to decode it again by using

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['arr']);
```

Another problem is the output-code. In php, you need to use `.` for concatination:

```
foreach ($arr as $i) 
{
    echo $i . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: And there is nothing wrong with sending an object. Even more: jQuery.post requires an object. In your code the array would be sent as an object, so you would need to loop over $_POST instead of $_POST['arr']

Comment: The reason it's in curly braces, is that I'm also sending other data. How would I work around that? (i.e. `$.post("url.php", {arr: $arr, foo: $foo, bar: $bar, baz: $baz});`)

Comment: Passing an *array* as the second argument to `$.post` is going to end up posting data like: `undefined=&undefined=&undefined=` (that's from `$.post('test', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);`). This just breaks things.

Comment: @Blaatpraat Could you provide an answer as to how one would accomplish that?

Comment: Try the following: `$.post("url.php", {arr: JSON.stringify($arr)});` and in your php `$arr = json_decode($_POST['arr']);` (maybe you can remove the stringify-part, since JQuery does that automatically)

Comment: @MichaelJarvis Just do what is told as a comment on your question: execute a var_dump on $_POST['arr'], and use a dot to concatenate instead of a plus.

Comment: @MichaelJarvis I identified the actual problem - see my updated answer.

Comment: @maja You're a lifesaver! However, it's printing as an array to the page: `List: ["Foo","Bar","Baz"]`. Could it be an issue with Firefox?

Comment: So... I've already told you twice, and MLeFevre did it too. Why didn't you try it when we already told you the problem? -_-

Comment: @MichaelJarvis The result doesn't depend on the browser - make a `var_dump($POST);` in your `php` and show us the output, it makes debugging for us much easier.

Comment: @Blaatpraat I did, no need to get funny. It produces the same result

Comment: @MichaelJarvis What does `var_dump($_POST);` in your php print?

Comment: @maja It does the same thing, and prints the list out

Answer (score 0):

JS side

```
$.post("url.php", {arr: json.Stringify($arr)});
```

PHP side

```
json_decode($_POST['arr']);
```

Comment: Unnecessary converting. The javascript part should do fine here.